# Setting less than and greater than values

Tags: python, hex

I am trying to set certain values for variables. The variables are for determining if a hex colour is green, red, blue, OR green and red, blue and red, or green and blue.

The value I am trying to set to determine if something is green and red vs just red or just green is to have a certain number range, in which something would be qualified as green AND red, etc...

E.G: FF0000 = Red. A1A100 = Red and Green, A1C124 = Red and Green.

My A1C124 code would have problems in my script, because it is difficult to just say

```
if
Red > Green or \
Red = Green and \
Red > Blue
    print red and green.
```

Because if that code were to run, anything that is clearly red would also come out as green and red.

So instead, I am trying to set a limit to how greater than green can red be, and vice-versa. And for that to happen, I need to set a range.

Something along the lines of:

```
redGreen = green +1
redGreen2 = green -1
redGreen3 = green + 2
redGreen4 = green - 2
```

And then I would set the code kind of like this:

```
if red > blue and \
   green > blue:
    redGreen = green +1
    redGreen2 = green -1
    redGreen3 = green + 2
    redGreen4 = green - 2
    print "This colour is red and green"
```

But there are 2 problems.

The above code does not work, as it just replaces the + 1 with the +2, and same for the negative values, and I for the life of me cannot understand any tutorials that teach me this.

So, does anyone know how to set a range? Or if there is a better method, can you explain what it is please?

Comment: Downvoters : It isn't useful to just click the downvote button.  You need to specify **why** you downvoted in a comment.  That way, the user can learn how things work on SO and update their question/ask better questions in the future.

Comment: Well, I guess I cannot really blame them. Humans are prejudiced beings. If I were to speak a language very badly in a country where that is the official language, many people would also dislike me. I guess it is the same on this website.

Though I wish I had gotten some feedback as to why I got the down votes. Was it that I was unclear with my question? Is it because of my fail coding that you are offended? Or is it that I have become the target of sad and depressed trolls lurking on the internet? I cannot tell.

Comment: @AjEntity: You are mistaking downvotes as personal attacks.  They are not.  And it's very unlikely anybody got *offended* by your post – there is nothing even vaguely offensive about it.

Comment: One common way to compare two numeric values is to see if the absolute value of their difference to is above or below some threshold. i.e. `if abs(a-b) > threshold: ...` There are, of course, other measures and methods such as those discussed in Wikipedia's article about [relative differences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_difference).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Admittedly, I did not manage to follow your post completely.  There's a chance, though, that converting the colour in question to [HSV space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) and looking at the hue value only will simplify what you are trying to do.

Python provides the function [`colorsys.rgb_to_hsv()`](http://docs.python.org/library/colorsys.html#colorsys.rgb_to_hsv) to perform this conversion.

Comment: That is genius. I did not even know that function existed. Is there a tutorial for it? I tried googling that specific code but I could not find out how to use it.

Comment: @AjEntity: There's example code at the bottom of the linked documentation.  And the linked Wikipedia page describes the HSV colour space.  You could also search for this term in Google, because the explanation on the Wikipedia page may be far too detailed.  Also note that the `colorsys` module uses floating point values in the range from `0.0` to `1.0` for all colour spaces.

Comment: @Aj Entity: To elaborate slightly on Sven's comment, it's very important to note that the "h" hue values expected and returned by the `colorsys` module's functions are not in the usual 0..360 degree angle range you see often used in articles about colorspaces.